# Show segue inexplicably changes to a modal segue when a container view controller is used

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I don't know the exact cause of this but I am guessing it has something to do with a container view controller being used. I am actually using several containers, one is for a `SWRevealViewController`, which houses a generic `UIViewController` for its rearViewController and a `UINavigationController` for the frontViewController. The root view controller of this navigation controller is another container view controller, a MainViewController, which contains a `UIPageViewController`. Page view controller has 3 `UITableViewController`s and when I try to navigate from those table view controllers to the relevant view controllers (via a segue), and I want it to be a push transition, it makes a modal transition so what gives?

It is something to do with hierarchy I guess, but it is kinda messed up with all these view controllers right now and I think I broke my brain at some point. I would really appreciate if someone who knows what is wrong can explain.

Comment: Too much text; brain hurts. It would be easier to understand if you post an image with your Storyboard and highlight your problem.

Comment: Need 10 reputation to post images... Don't think it can be inferred from the storyboard.

Comment: Good luck - with no code and just a wall of hard-to-interpret text you will be lucky to get a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the replies but I got it working without the use of segues and the storyboard, by pushing the view controller in tableView delegate manually, like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    PlaceViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"placeViewController"];
    vc.place = self.places[indexPath.row];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

was stuck with the same problem and tried to solve for almost 2 days, and finally solved that..

View Hierarchy:

Container View

- First Controller (direct child of container)
- Second Controller (direct child of container)

  - Third Controller
  - Fourth Controller

Solution

- added Navigation controller to First Controller
- added Navigation Controller to Second Controller

and when want to display any controller instead of presenting the controller itself present the UINavigationController, this will solve the problem of not happening segue push animation...

sample code, hoping it will help:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var loginViewNavigation  : UINavigationController!
    var singupViewNavigation : UINavigationController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "User", bundle: nil)

        loginViewNavigation  = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewNavigation") as! UINavigationController
        singupViewNavigation = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SignupViewNavigation") as! UINavigationController

        self.addChildViewController(loginViewNavigation)
        self.addChildViewController(singupViewNavigation)

        self.view.addSubview(loginViewNavigation.view)
    }
}
```

Point to observe is the use the UINavigationController of the controller you want to display instead of that ViewController

Comment: Did something like this myself, it seemed like it worked. But this feels unsatisfying and I want to know what causes this. The answer is correct actually, but just need to know why this damn machine behave like this. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: The UINavigationController is a Cocoa Touch class which manages a stack of UIView controllers (and their respective views). The nav controller is separate from the UINavigationBar (the bar that appears at the top of a view); a navigation controller may exist without a navigation bar.

Views are managed by pushing/popping them on/off the nav controller's view stack. When you push an item, the current view slides off screen to the left, and the new view slides over from the right.

Comment: Also here given the special characteristics of UINavigationController, is very helpful: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/

Comment: Yes I know all of these stuff. I already have different navigation controllers for each child of the container. Problem must be somewhere else but I got it working without the segues, programmatically. Thank you anyway.